# Accessing server side page Error

Tags: javascript, php, client-server, server-side

I am new to web development 
I have created a project which I host on local Apache Server 
I developed this project with IE8 browser and Developer tools

But now when I open with chrome browser it does not hit the request with error stating as  Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I read and browsed through stackoverflow sites and web they say its problem of CORS or Same Origin policy after that I got to know that this can be resolved by adding a  php script

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

But since I cannot over ride the server side

I tried it on my client side page by adding the above script but still it gave the same error  Origin `http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I have suppose two pages first Login.html and second SecondPage.html

I have included the above code in Login.html in header part as seen below

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>

    <!-- Basics -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_files/login6.js"></script>

     <script script language="javascript" src="js_files/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>



</head>
```

Am I right ??

Or should I include the same in SecondPage.html

Comment: The HTML of the page doesn't really tell us a lot on its own. If the error is coming from JavaScript, we need to see that JavaScript in order to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to send any headers at the very beginning of your document. And don't foget your opening html-tag. Like this:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
```